# Swift TableViewCell empty when cell has values

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, model-view-controller

I have a custom cell with some simple labels and a UIImage. Everything appears to be set correctly, and stepping through the debugger shows that everything is getting a value and even using the print  in the debugger shows that the labels have text. However my table view is still empty when executed. I have been looking at this for too long and cannot figure out the problem.

Here is the cell code

```
class CurrentFileCell: UITableViewCell {


@IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var statusImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var dateLabel: UILabel!


var currentContent: AircraftContent! {
    didSet{
        setStyles(Constants.appStyleSetting)

        self.nameLabel.text = currentContent.contentName
        self.dateLabel.text = currentContent.contentStatus
        self.statusImage.image = UIImage(named: "color_label_circle_green")

    }
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
}

private func setStyles(settings: StyleSettings) {
    let tableFont = UIFont(name: settings.bodyFont, size: CGFloat(settings.tableFontSize))
    nameLabel.font = tableFont
    dateLabel.font = tableFont

    // Text color
    let tableFontColor = settings.tableFontColor
    nameLabel.textColor = tableFontColor
    dateLabel.textColor = tableFontColor
}
```

Here is the ViewController code with a tableview inside.

```
class CurrentFilesViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

var content: AircraftContent?

@IBOutlet weak var currentFiles: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var downloadingLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var readyLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tableView.delegate = self
    self.tableView.dataSource = self

    self.content = loadContent()
    setStyles(Constants.appStyleSetting)
    //self.tableView.reloadData()
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CurrentFileCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? CurrentFileCell
    cell?.currentContent = content

    return cell!
}


func loadContent() -> AircraftContent {
    return (NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile(AircraftContent.ArchiveURL.path!) as? AircraftContent)!
}

private func setStyles(settings: StyleSettings) {
    let titleFont = UIFont(name: settings.bodyFont, size: CGFloat(settings.titleFontSize))
    let key = UIFont(name: settings.bodyFont, size: CGFloat(settings.tableFontSize))
    currentFiles.font = titleFont
    downloadingLabel.font = key
    readyLabel.font = key

    // Text color
    let titleFontColor = settings.titleFontColor
    currentFiles.textColor = titleFontColor
    downloadingLabel.textColor = titleFontColor
    readyLabel.textColor = titleFontColor

}
```

Here are some images showing the debug location where the cell is not empty, and also printing out the label which has a value, but isn't being shown during simulation.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6MoGA.jpg

This is an image showing the prototype cell. The cell has the correct class set as well as the identifier.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wmJL.jpg

Lastly another image showing that the prototype cell is linked to the labels within the CurrentFileCell.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6lIF.jpg

Any help at all with this would be appreciated. I have tried recreating everything but continue to be stumped as it seems like everything is how it should be.

Comment: where is your data array?

Comment: Have you tried executing the didSet of currentContent in the main thread?

Comment: I do not have a data array, only the one variable right now. @Ozgur Ersil

Comment: What do you mean by that exactly? I shouldn't have to set it, but only update the object of the cell. @Caelan

Comment: Make sure you register the custom class with the tableView as well.

Comment: how does one do this @Ike10 ?

Comment: I put it in an answer so it would be easier to read and I could elaborate.

Comment: @John511 Check out my answer, and let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement the 'heightForRowAtIndexPath' method for the table view

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

        let height:CGFloat = 75
        return height

}
```

Comment: I tried this with multiple different heights and it doesn't change anything. It is still just an empty cell. Any ideas?

Comment: Hmm my next guess would be along the lines of Ike10's. Make sure you declared the cells reuse identifier in the inspector pane in the story board and also make sure you registered the class. You could either do this in the story board or programmatically like Ike10's answer

Answer (score 0):

You may consider registering the custom class as it does not appear that you did. You can do that by using the following code in the `viewDidLoad` of your View Controller.

```
tableView.registerClass(CurrentFileCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
```

If you are using an external nib you will want to use `registerNib` instead like so:

```
tableView.registerNib(UINib(name:"ReplaceWithYourNibName", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "ReuseIdentifier")
```

Of course, replace `ReplaceWithYourNibName` and `ReuseIdentifier` with the appropriate values. In addition, if your nib is in a different bundle specify that instead of nil (nil defaults to the main bundle).

However, do not use both `registerClass` and `registerNib` as whichever one you call last will be used and they were designed to be mutually exclusive. Whenever you make a custom `UITableViewCell` you must use either of the two for it to work unless you have set it explicitly in the storyboard.

Also, you could **instead**, use prototype cells to define your custom cell, which would, I believe, automatically register the cell. But **only** if you did not use prototype cells make sure to use `registerClass` or `registerNib`.

Good luck! Hope this helps!

Comment: I have used this but now it is giving me a weird error in my custom cell class. It is trying to set the values of the labels but it is getting an error saying unwrapping an optional nil value. Here is a location of the debugger also showing that the text is valid. http://imgur.com/xWEirpp

Comment: Try forcing the cast when you use `dequeReusableCellWithIdentifier` (forIndexPath). so like `let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CurrentFileCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CurrentFileCell`

Comment: Still the same thing happening. Just an empty cell with nothing in it. Even if I put something in the cell that never changes or gets edited it just doesn't show up. Regardless of what it is, an empty cell is present. I have used this same tableview method with custom cells in 2 other places within my project and have had no issues so I am just at a loss for what is occurring here.

Answer (score 0):

If your cell is a static cell, then you need to comment out these methods in UITableViewDataSource:

```
/*    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
 // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 0
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return 0
} */
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
Data has values and cell rows are showing empty.
I figured it by adding

```
contentView.addSubview(titleLabel)
```

where cell values are being set.